# react-table 'pivotBy' : How can i make filterable on the columns used in pivotBy

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

In react-table, when we use 'pivotBy' option we will be mentioning the column names as

```
pivotBy={["state", "city"]}
```

and in the

```
columns={[
  // we only require the accessor so TreeTable
  // can handle the pivot automatically
  {
    accessor: "state",
  },
  {
    accessor: "city"
  },
  // any other columns we want to display
  {
    Header: "First Name",
    accessor: "first_name",
  },  
]}
```

I can able to get filter option for first_name but not able to get the filter options for the column name mentioned in pivotBy.

How can i get filter options for state and city?